# Почему ухудшается качество отображаемой фотографии

Tags: java, android, bitmap

Вывожу на экран фотографию:

```
Bitmap bitmap = decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(data, 100, 100);
```

Метод decodeSampledBitmapFromResource() выглядит вот так:

```
  public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(String path,
                                                         int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

        // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);

        // Calculate inSampleSize
        options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

        // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);
    }
```

При повороте фотографии на 90 градусов с помощью `Matrix` фотография стает размытой:

```
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postRotate(90);
    Bitmap bitmap = decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(data, 100, 100);
    bitmap=Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
```

Почему ухудшается качество фотографии? И как сделать, что бы она была в нормальном качестве?

Comment: могу только предлодить попробовать поставить последний параметр false.

Comment: @metalurgus не помогло :(

Comment: @Lucky_girl возможное решение проблемы http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4821488/bad-image-quality-after-resizing-scaling-bitmap